# Filtering products by attributes in magento

Tags: magento

How do i list products with a specific attribute? for example if Size is an attribute in my default attribute set. Then how do i list all the products which has Size = 22?

I am searching google for the answer, will post as answer if i find any.

Thanks,

Balan

Answer (score 1):

I just did this not too long ago

To get the store id:

```
$storeId  = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
```

To get all the products filtering out everything but Size

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter("Size", "1");
```

Then simply in a foreach loop add the following(this will loop through the array $_productCollection)

```
foreach($_productCollection as $_product)
{
    $attr = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($_product->getId(), 'Size', $storeId);
    if($attr == '22')
    {
        //Echo names of the products
        echo $_product->getName();
    }
}
```

This way you can still do a lot with the product list without having a strict listing of products. So you can still add names, prices, and more attributes if you wish. Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
    $storeId  = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');    

    $products->addAttributeToFilter(array(
                   array('attribute' => 'attribute_code', 'eq' => 22)))
                   ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                              ->setStoreId($storeId)
                              ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
                  ->setOrder('name', 'desc'); 

      Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);  
  Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);
 $this->setProductCollection($products);
```

for me this works fine.

Comment: when i use this code i get the error : "Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the catalog product is made for this. The best would be to move the attribute Size in the static table (catalog_product_entity). Then you will be able to search by size with keeping the catalog fast. After if you want to do this on different attribute, I guess you can give it as parameter in the collection. But I am not sure about it.